# post Multiple FormData() to Node Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, multipartform-data

So , i have three forms to be submitted at one click.

When submitted, the data collected from the three forms must create three rows in the DB through an API triggering a POST request

How do i pass the variable alldata to the API?

If i pass only one of them as data1, it perfectly works. But passing them as an array is not.

Appreciate your help.

```
const data1 = new FormData()
data1.set("images", values.image1)
data1.set("detail", values.detail1)
const data2 = new FormData()
data1.set("images", values.image2)
data1.set("detail", values.detail2)
const data3 = new FormData()
data1.set("images", values.image3)
data1.set("detail", values.detail3)


var alldata = [data1,data2,data3]



const res =  axios(
"post",
"/APIGOESHERE"
alldata
)
```

Comment: huh... have you considered using only one formData?

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass one form at a time. You can just put all the parameters in the same `FormData` object. Give them all the same name and Express will collect them in an array. Use the `append()` method to add multiple items with the same name; `set` will replace the item.

```
const data1 = new FormData()
data1.append("images", values.image1)
data1.append("detail", values.detail1)
data1.append("images", values.image2)
data1.append("detail", values.detail2)
data1.append("images", values.image3)
data1.append("detail", values.detail3)

const res =  axios(
    "post",
    "/APIGOESHERE"
    data1
)
```

Comment: and how you then access this on the backend? I'm doing something like:

upload.fields([
  { name: "images", maxCount: 1 },
  { name: "detail", maxCount: 1 },
 ]),

and I get unexpected end of form

Comment: Are you using `multer`? It will aid with processing multipart/form-data. You can find tutorials on it.

Comment: would you mind having a look at this please? You might spot something that I couldn't: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064309/unexpected-end-of-form-at-callfinal-error

Comment: I'm not a node.js/Express expert.

Comment: Oh thats fair enough! Ignore me then, I'll try looking intro this further