# Unexpected end of form at .callFinal error

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, multer, body-parser

I'm trying to send a new FormData() as the body of a POST request using axios and Multer to handle multipart form data, locally it works without any issues but on our live envs I keep getting `Unexpected end of form at .callFinal`. The content-type seems to be the expected  `multipart/form-data` with the set boundary. But it still this gives this error. I've found similar threads on stackoverflow, this one was the closest to mine: [Unexpected end of form error when using Multer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72544409/unexpected-end-of-form-error-when-using-multer) but none of the answeres seemed to solve the issue for me. (I haven't tried downgrading as I don't think that would be the main issue here)

I've tried:

- Setting the header manually but when not setting it defaults back to the correct `multipart/form-data`
- Adding `bodyParser.json({extended:true})` before the multer middleware
- Removing bodyParser.json() from express level
- Switching the middleware to `express-fileupload`
- Switching up the order of the Form Data items to have file at the end
- Using different HTTP clients to send the request

But still getting the same error. Any ideas on what can cause this?

I'm on Multer version: `1.4.5-lts.1`

This is the api call:

```js
export const uploadFiles = async {
    formData: FormData;
    groupId:string
) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: `${EnvironmentUtils.getBaseUrl()}/files/upload`,
            params: {
                groupId,
            },
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                ApiKey: EnvironmentUtils.getApiKey(),
            },
            withCredentials: true,
    } catch (err) {
        const publicErrMsg = err?.response?.data?.message;
        throw new Error(
            `Error when uploading file: ${publicErrMsg || err.message}`,
        );
    }
};
```

This is where data being appended to formData:

```js
const upload = useCallback(
        async (files: FileList) => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("filesData", files[0]);
            formData.append("folderPath", btoa(selectedFolderPath || ""));
            formData.append("friendlyName", files[0].name);
            try {
                const res = await uploadFiles(
                    formData,
                    groupId
                );
```

And on the backend the middleware is:

```js
export const upload = Multer({
    storage: Multer.memoryStorage(),
    limits: {
        fileSize:
            FirebaseUtils.getEnvironmentVar("multer.max.file_size") ||
            10 * 1024 * 1024, // No larger than 10mb
        fieldSize:
            FirebaseUtils.getEnvironmentVar("multer.max.field_size") ||
            10 * 1024 * 1024, // No larger than 10mb
    },
});
```

Router:

```js
app.post(
    "/files/upload",
    authManager,
    MulterMiddleware.upload.single("filesData"),
    Controller.handlePostFileUploads,
);
```

And then getting the file data from `req.file` in `handlePostFileUploads` like this:

```js
export const handlePostFileUploads: RequestHandler = async (req, res) => {
    const groupId = req.groupId!;

    const file = req.file;
    const { folderPath, friendlyName } = req.body; // Can this be the issue?
```

I think the issue probably lies somewhere on the Multer middleware side but I'm not exactly sure what I'm missing

In my server I have the following set:

Server.js

```js
const express = require("express")();
express.use(bodyParser.json());
```

There might be a collision between bodyParser and multer here?

Comment: Are you running this behind an AWS ELB by any change? Or is the client an AWS Lambda function?